# Prepend to div, but after first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to prepend (newest first) new divisions to my `.container` but after `.controls` (buttons). Is it possible?

Note: Adding new division that will hold prepended controls below buttons is **NOT** an option for me. HTML needs to be intact.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MhRmy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MhRmy/2/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.add').on('click', function(){
        $('.controls').after('<div class="new-control"></div>');
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

One option:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add').bind('click', function(){
        $('<div />',{class: 'new-control'})
            .insertAfter($('.container .controls'));
    });
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MhRmy/1/).

And another:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.add').bind('click', function(){
        $('<div />',{class: 'new-control'})
            .appendTo($('.container'));
    });
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MhRmy/3/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).

Comment: +1 for accessing el specifics with `{}` instead of `$('<div class="new-control" />')`

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method to add elements as siblings of a given element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add').bind('click', function(){
    $('.container .controls').after('<div class="new-control"></div>');
  });
});​
```